# Simplify/shorten TextView assignments

Tags: java, android

To get six different TextViews that are used in the Activity I am using the following code.

```
txtName[0] = findViewById(R.id.txtName1);            
txtName[1] = findViewById(R.id.txtName2);            
txtName[2] = findViewById(R.id.txtName3);            
txtName[3] = findViewById(R.id.txtName4);            
txtName[4] = findViewById(R.id.txtName5);            
txtName[5] = findViewById(R.id.txtName6);
```

How can I simplify/shorten this? Each `TextView` is together with other views part of `RelativeLayout`. All `RelativeLayout`s are grouped by a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Can you give some more context? do you want to shrink your code so that you dont have to reference indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Put the ids in an array and loop over them:

```
int[] ids = { R.id.txtName1, R.id.txtName2, R.id.txtName3,
              R.id.txtName4, R.id.txtName5, R.id.txtName6 };
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
    txtName[i] = findViewById(ids[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two points to simplify.

**(1) Modify labeling of R.id.***

There is numbering gap or shift between the labels of `R.id.txtNameX` and the indices of integer array `txtName[i]`. I would refactor that for better readability.

```
txtName[0] = findViewById(R.id.txtName0);            
txtName[1] = findViewById(R.id.txtName1);            
txtName[2] = findViewById(R.id.txtName2);            
txtName[3] = findViewById(R.id.txtName3);            
txtName[4] = findViewById(R.id.txtName4);            
txtName[5] = findViewById(R.id.txtName5);
```

**(2) Generate each Resource ID from number**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(
        "txtName" + String.valueOf(i),
        "id",
        getPackageName()
    );
    txtName[i] = findViewById(resourceId);
}
```

**(2a) In case you don't want to modify labels of R.id.***

You need to use `i + 1` instead of `i`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(
        "txtName" + String.valueOf(i + 1),
        "id",
        getPackageName()
    );
    txtName[i] = findViewById(resourceId);
}
```